# Can ASP.NET MVC3 Applications Host in cloud without specific code changes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cloud-hosting, appharbor

I had created an ASP.NET web app using:

- ASP.NET MVC 3 Webforms
- Linq to sql
- MS SQL Server database
- WCF

What would need to be done to host it on a cloud service? Should i convert it in to Azure application or not. can i directly upload my ASP.Net MVC Web application in a Cloud without specific code changes that would be required before hosting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please understand that there is no need to change your code to host your application in cloud.
Cloud hosting is nothing but a traditional hosting with advanced infrastructure. Yes, you can directly upload my ASP.Net MVC Web application in a Cloud without specific code changes

You only need to change your code, if you want to add CDN hosting with the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You can push your application to [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) with no modifications, and we'll run and scale your app in the cloud with no modifications.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of AppHarbor)