# Cloud Hosting for ASP.Net 3.5 and related concerns

Tags: asp.net-3.5, cloud-hosting

I have developed an ASP.Net (VB.Net) website which is using Entity Framework and SQL Server 2005 Express.

My Client has just told me that he wants his website to be hosted in some cloud environment.

I have to ask that will there be issues? I mean

1. Are there some things which should be kept in mind while developing an application which is supposed to be hosted in Cloud Environment?
2. Do I have to change my code? (I am using Session for the Login purpose) or will my existing code will be working without any change? Currently my code is running fine on a shared ASP.Net 3.5 hosting provider.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I love when clients demand buzzwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please understand that there is no need to change your code to host your application in cloud. Cloud hosting is nothing but a traditional hosting with advanced infrastructure having fail-over protection for hardwares. Following article will be helpful for you ...

[Can ASP.NET MVC3 Applications Host in cloud without specific code changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007236/can-asp-net-mvc3-applications-host-in-cloud-without-specific-code-changes/10370182#10370182)

Your Question: Do I have to change my code? (I am using Session for the Login purpose) or will my existing code will be working without any change? Currently my code is running fine on a shared ASP.Net 3.5 hosting provider.

> > > > > Yes, you can directly upload you ASP.Net MVC Web application in a Windows Cloud without specific code changes ... I am hosting my couple of applications at [AccuWebHosting.Com](http://www.accuwebhosting.com/) windows public cloud servers.

Answer (score 1):

There are definitely some things to keep in mind:

- If you want your app to be able to scale to multiple instances, you should be very mindful of any shared state, in your case in-memory session state. Here's an article on [using Memcached for session-state storage](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/using-memcached-backed-sessionprovider) on [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/)
- Many cloud providers operate with a paradigm where filesystem storage on instance filesystems are not persisted which means that you have to store user-generated file content somewhere like [AWS S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Other than things like that, your app should not require modifications (on note that those are only necessary if your app takes file uploads or if you plan to scale it to multiple instances).